# Stack smashing in Scrabble mini game program

Tags: c

Below is a code fragment from a program called scrabble.c that is being used to play a simplified version of the game. The user is dealt 7 random characters and then told to enter a word using those characters.  I am having a problem with the function that takes the user input and stores it in a array.

This fuction should prompt the user to enter a word, then read it, and store it character by character in the array "word". The function should also return the size of the word entered by the user (the number of letters entered).

```
int read_word(char word[7], int max_size_word)
{
int c = 0, input_count = 0;
printf("Please enter your word : ");

char user_input = getchar();
for(c = 0; c < max_size_word; c++)
{
    if(user_input != '\n')
    {
    word[input_count] = user_input; 
    input_count++;
    printf("input_count = %d, letter entered = %c\n", input_count, 
user_input);
    }
    else if(user_input == '\n')
    {
    return input_count;
    }
    user_input = getchar();
}
return input_count;
```

// Error happens around here. Error : Stack Smashing Detected ./scrabble terminated Aborted core dumped."

Why is stack smashing being detected?

```
}

int main(void)
{
int t;
int letter_set[7] = {0};
char word[7];
int size_letter_set = 100;
int num_letters = 7;

generate_letter_set(&letter_set[7], size_letter_set, num_letters);
read_word(&word[7], 7);
printf("printing word : ");

for(t=0; t < 7; t++)
{
    printf("%c", word[t]);
}
    printf("\n");


 return 0;
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

You call functions with both:

```
&letter_set[7]
&word[7]
```

That is a pointer to the eighth int/character in the 7 int/character arrays. Just use `letter_set` and `word` when calling the functions. Your stack can get smashed when your code starts writing to the array. Similarly, the function prototype would be better as:

```
int read_word(char word[], int max_size_word)
```

The `7` doesn't do anything special there, so just drop it.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is here

```
read_word(&word[7], 7);
```

you are passing to `read_word` not the address of the array `word` of size 7 as you might have thought but the address of `word[7]` which points to the **8th** character of `word` which is out of the boundary.

To pass the array address write the following:

```
read_word(&word[0], 7);
```

or

```
read_word(word, 7);
```

---

The same is regarding `generate_letter_set(&letter_set[7], size_letter_set, num_letters);`